# How to get different ng-model values in ng-include of the same HTML file

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-ng-include

There are two html files:

index1.html

```
<input type="text" ng-model="model.Name">
<!-- Some complex form !-->
```

index.html

```
<div>Journalist's Details:
    Name:<div ng-include="index1.html"></div>
</div>
<div ng-if="isCompanionNeeded">Journalist's Companion Details:
    Name:<div ng-include="index1.html"></div>
</div>
```

Here ,I'd want "Journalist.Name" in place of the "model.Name" for the "Journalist's Details:" part of the form and "Companion.Name" in place of "model.Name" for the "Journalist's Companion Details:
" part , as using the same model name will just get me same values in both the name fields and any other fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using AngularJS v1.5+, you can use component instead of ng-include. This is an example of a component you could create

**Component JS**

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .component('myDetailsComponent', {
        bindings: {
            data: '<'
        },
        controller: function () {
            // do whatever you need with your input here            
        },
        templateUrl: 'my-details.component.html'
    });
```

**Component Template**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.data.Name">
```

**View**

```
<div>
    <p>Journalist's Details:</p>
    <my-details-component data="companion"></my-details-component>
</div>
```

**Edit**

If you are using an older version of AngularJS, you can replicate the same functionality with a directive. For example:

**Directive JS**

```
angular
    .module('myDetailsDirective')
    .directive('myDetailsDirective', myDetailsDirective);


function myDetailsDirective() {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            data: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'my-details.directive.html',
        link: function () {
            // do whatever you need with your input here   
        }
    };

}
```

**Directive Template**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="data.Name">
```

**View**

The usage of the directive is exactly the same as in the case of the component:

```
<div>
    <p>Journalist's Details:</p>
    <my-details-directive data="companion"></my-details-directive>
</div>
```

Comment: Great,this is exactly what I wanted.
Thanks a ton :)

Comment: I added the directive example as well.

Answer (score 1):

The `ng-model` in the index.html needs to have something like a `companion.Name` object in order to be accessible.

Create a file called index2.html with

```
<input type="text" ng-model="companion.Name">
```

and include it in your index.html

```
   <div>Journalist's Details:
       Name:<div ng-include="index1.html"></div>
   </div>
   <div ng-if="isCompanionNeeded">Journalist's Companion Details:
       Name:<div ng-include="index2.html"></div>
   </div
```

Comment: Thanks, but my problem here is the _index1.html_  that i am using doesn't have just one input tag , rather it is a full-fledged form even with some other <div ng-include"Employer's Details" so won't it be too cumbersome to write that entire thing again and put more load on the app?

Comment: Well the thing is that the model is bound to `model.Name`. If you include said .html file it will always be bound to the same model and all the changes applied to `model.Name` will be reflected in both includes.

Comment: Isn't there some way to make the value of ng-model dynamic?

Comment: @Anton I don't think this solves OP's problem. At least not in a hustle-free way.